# MySQL Query WHERE `Field_x` - `Field_y` is lower than equal

Tags: mysql

I don't Know How can I execute a query to select where field_x (minus) field_y lower than equal ?

Sample :     `SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE Field_X - Fiel_Y < 50`

Comment: What do you mean by "lower than equal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question this should be it

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Field_X - Field_Y <= 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean lower or equal than some constant?

```
SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE Field_X - Field_Y <= 50
```